# How do I insert random values from api data into HTML onclick?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to be able to add a new user on click of a plus button, that fetches data from a randomly generated API. However, I am having trouble inserting the values as they are currently undefined and unsure how to resolve them.

```
    <div id="btn" onclick="createUser()">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
    </div>
        <div id="cards">
        
        </div>

function createUser() {
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card');

    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
          data((userData) => {
            card.innerHTML = `
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="imgBorder">
                    <img src=` + userData.large `/>
                </div>
                <h4 class="subtitle is-4">` + userData.first + userData.last `</h4>
                <div class="details">
                    <div class="detail">
                        <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                        <span>` + userData.email `</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                        <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                        <span>` + userData.phone `</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                        <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
                        <span>` + userData.date `</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
          });
          document.getElementById('cards').appendChild(card);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow your code is a mess,

some of the issues listed here:

- `<img src=" + userData.large "/>` is no valid syntax, take a look at escape strings
- Your json unwrap is incorrect, take a look at the structure of the json object otherwise things like `userData.large` will return null because this key is not defined
- `.then(data => { data((userData) => {...})})` is invalid, data is not a function, so don't try calling it

For a functional example check this out:

```js
function createUser() {
  const card = document.createElement('div');
  card.classList.add('card');

  fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      userData = data.results[0]
      const card = `
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="imgBorder">
                <img src="${userData.picture.large}"/>
            </div>
            <h4 class="subtitle is-4">${userData.name.first}${userData.name.last}</h4>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="detail">
                    <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                    <span>${userData.email}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="detail">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                    <span>${userData.phone}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="detail">
                    <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
                    <span>${userData.dob.date}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
      document.getElementById('cards').innerHTML += card;
    });
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="createUser()">Click me</button>
<div id="cards"></div>
```

**Note**

Please keep in mind that creating HTMLElements from strings and adding them to the DOM is a really insecure operation due to XSS vulernabilities.
Maybe you'd like to escape the strings coming from the API before inserting them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have issue with your html template. Please try the below code

```
function createUser() {

    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
          data((userData) => {
           const card = document.createElement('div');
           card.classList.add('card');

           card.innerHTML = `
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="imgBorder">
                    <img src=${userData.large}/>
                </div>
                <h4 class="subtitle is-4">${userData.first} ${userData.last}</h4>
                <div class="details">
                    <div class="detail">
                        <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                        <span>${userData.email}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                        <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                        <span>${userData.phone}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                        <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
                        <span>${userData.date}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
          });
          document.getElementById('cards').appendChild(card);
    });
}
```